# Ordering an array with the smallest value first MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I'm trying to get the smallest value in the 2D array but keep the order of the 2D array, for example:

If I had the array

```
7  |  7

2  |  3

8  |  0

3  |  7

5  |  5
```

I want to order it so it displays

```
2  |  3

8  |  0

3  |  7

5  |  5

7  |  7
```

I've looked at `mink` and `sortrows` but none seem to give the output I need.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I used a bad example, I've updated my question. @SardarUsama

Comment: Now I'm more confused. What sorting criterion are you using?

Comment: So I want the smallest value on the left to be the first, cycling through the array, removing values at the top and adding them at the bottom of the array so that the order or the array is not lost.

Comment: That would be a good thing to add to the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) to change the order of the elements in the way you need. First find the index to the minimal element, then shift so that the element is at the top:

```
M = [7,7   % example data from OP
     2,3
     8,0
     3,7
     5,5];

[~,ind] = min(M(:,1));
M = circshift(M,1-ind,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the updated question, you first need to identify the row that you want to be moved to the top of the matrix. Once you know this you can simply rearrange the matrix so that this row, and all that occur after it, are placed first.

```
A = [7     7
     2     3
     8     0
     3     7
     5     5]
[~,index] = min(A(:,1)); % Identify row which should occur first
A = A([index:end,1:(index-1)], :) % Rearrange rows
A =
     2     3
     8     0
     3     7
     5     5
     7     7
```